# Convert an rgb string to a Color32

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, tryparse

I have data coming in from a JSON file with a bunch of RGB strings in the format `color: '255,255,255'` - I want to colorize things in Unity by reading that string and converting it to a color32, but I can't figure out how to convert these to the format that Unity needs: `new Color32(255,255,255,255)`.

How do I convert the string into a color32?

I've succesfully gotten it into an array of integers, but I'm getting a `cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type int` error when I attempt to do:

```
int awayColor = team2Data.colors[0];
awayBG.color = new Color32(awayColor[0],awayColor[1],awayColor[2],255);
```

with a data structure that looks like:

```
"colors": [
        [225,68,52],
        [196,214,0],
        [38,40,42]
      ]
```

The classes I'm using to parse the JSON are:

```
[System.Serializable]
    public class TeamData
    {
        public List<Team> teams = new List<Team>();
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Team
    {
        public int[] colors;
        public string id;
    }
```

and the function I'm using is:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, teamDataFile);
//string filePath = teamDataFile;
if(File.Exists(filePath))
{
    string dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    //Debug.Log(dataAsJson);
    teamData = JsonUtility.FromJson<TeamData>(dataAsJson);
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Cannot load game data!");
}
```

The original JSON looks like:

```
{
      "id": "ATL",
      "colors": [
        "225,68,52",
        "196,214,0",
        "38,40,42"
      ]
    },
```

Comment: Can you post the complete json data?

Comment: If you already have the string, and without the data Programmer asked for, I would split the string using the comma delimiter, then clean up the first and last value by removing `color: '` from the first string, and `'` from the last string, convert all 3 to a byte and pass that to the constructor.  The 4th parameter is the alpha, if you are not storing that then it is probably fully opaque so pass 255 to the a.

Comment: AwayColors is an `int`, not an `int[]` that is why you are getting that error.

Comment: Have you tried casting `awayColor[x]` as a byte?

Comment: I tried declaring it as an `int[]` and get `cannot implictly convert type int to int[]` - even though in my class I'm setting colors as `public int[] colors;`. I think this is the problem - because it's a multidimensional array, it's actually logging the top level array out as `[0,0,0]` with no child arrays. Maybe I need another class to parse that second dimension of arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the `Color32` constructor:

```
public Color32(byte r, byte g, byte b, byte a) {...}
```

It takes `byte` as parameter not `int`. You're passing `int` to it because the `awayColor` variable is an `int`. Also, the `awayColor` variable is not an array but you're doing `awayColor[0]` and `awayColor[1]`.

---

Given the json below:

```
{
      "id": "ATL",
      "colors": [
        "225,68,52",
        "196,214,0",
        "38,40,42"
      ]
}
```

Below is a class to deserialize it into (<sup>Generated from [this](http://json2csharp.com/)</sup>):

```
[Serializable]
public class ColorInfo
{
    public string id;
    public List<string> colors;
}
```

Retrive the color json value

```
string json = "{\r\n      \"id\": \"ATL\",\r\n      \"colors\": [\r\n        \"225,68,52\",\r\n  
ColorInfo obj = JsonUtility.FromJson<ColorInfo>(json);
```

Get the first color in the List and trim it

```
string firstColor = obj.colors[0];
firstColor = firstColor.Trim();
```

Split it into 3 by the commas then convert it into byte array

```
byte[] color = Array.ConvertAll(firstColor.Split(','), byte.Parse);
```

Create `Color32` from the color byte array

```
Color32 rbgColor = new Color32(color[0], color[1], color[2], 255);
```